# Checking for Null Attribute in Thymeleaf Template

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and am trying to check for a null attribute in my template

```
<form th:action="@{/saveUser/__${user.id}__}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
```

The form submits fine if I am editing an existing user with an id already defined, however using the same form to add a new user I get the following

```
HTTP Status 400 - http://localhost:8080/myApp/saveUser/null"
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    userRepo.save(user); //JPA Repo
    return "success";
}
```

My thought is if I can check for the null id I can plug in a unique one somehow. Better yet, if I could make use of the `@GeneratedValue` set on my User object's ID then I think I'd be in good shape

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

**EDIT** Including my user edit form method which returns the same form but pre-populated with the User's model Attributes

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getUserEditForm(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userForm");
    User user = userRepo.findOne(id);
    mav.addObject("userForm", user);
    return mav; 
}
```

**EDIT 2** Including my whole form (ID is "hidden" from user)

```
<form th:action="@{/saveUser/__${user.id}__}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <input id="id" type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" /> 
    <input id="id" type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
    <input id="id" type="text" th:field="*{address}" />
    <button id="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: show your new user method code

Comment: Above is my new user method, I'm trying to use the JPA Repository for adding new and updating existing users

Comment: i only see saveUser method in your question which is not new user method. show the method that renders the new user form first time around before submitting to saveUser

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that they are the same method. addUser == saveUser. I've included my Edit method which will return the same view/user form but with the form pre-populated.

Comment: ok so i will provide answer based on fact that when you call the saveUser method the form doesn't work.

Comment: Right, the user.id is null when submitting the form (this should not be explicitly set) so I'm trying to auto-generate this id

Comment: To be honest its redundant passing {id} as parameter considering you are submitting whole user object anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion assuming that the following method is the one you call which should populate the user object and thus form fails on submission:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    userRepo.save(user); //JPA Repo
    return "success";
}
```

The reason that method doesn't work is because you are potentially passing an empty user object to begin with.
To remediate this you need to implement checks to ensure object is not null prior to calling the page.

one solution could be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    userRepo.save(user); //JPA Repo

    if(user == null)         // check if user object is empty
       user = new User();    // if user is empty, then instantiate a new user object

    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "success";
}
```

The above will ensure that when you passing user object to the model, it is always available.

Comment: Thanks @Aeseir I will look into this tomorrow l, though I think the problem lies within the template - specifically the ${user.id}. This is a necessary attribute when updating a user but problematic when adding a new. Anyhow I'll get back to you in the am

Comment: you need to ensure your form exposes all the fields at least using input hidden type. Otherwise you will lose critical data when saving to database. Also your database should be allocating the identify upon save not prior. It will allocate the next id number based on the existing sequence in table.

Comment: I'm using a hidden text field already to store the ID (which I'm trying to replace with a more secure method). I've included the rest my form

Comment: The problem is that my Controller method never gets called because the URL never matches the `@RequestMapping` due to the null value: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/saveUser/null` which should be `http://localhost:8080/myApp/saveUser/idPlaceholder`

Comment: Just get rid of the id field from mapping and form action. As said it's redundant and you making your code more complex for no extra benefit. Think simple and clean

Comment: @ClayBanks did this answer sort out your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've temporarily resolved this by creating a new `@Controller` to accept "null" at the end of the `@RequestMapping` (which kind of makes sense when creating a new user with a dynamic ID?), and just reimplementing the same logic. So when this is called

http://localhost:8080/myApp/saveUser/null"

It is mapped to my new Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser/null", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,  Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    userRepo.save(user);
    return "success";
}
```